# Merging and appending dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am tasked with taking dictionaries of classes with students names and there grades for the each class like below

```
History = {"bob": 20, "alex" :80}

Maths = {"harry": 50, "bob" : 90}

english = {"alex" : 40, "lee" : 20}

art = {"lee" : 70, "harry" :40}
```

and then putting the student scores from each class into one final dictionary as below

```
Final = {"alex":80,40 , "bob":20,90 , "harry":50,40 , "lee":20,70}
```

I have successfully managed to put all the classes in to one big dictionary but I cant manage to get the multiple value for each of the student names. The closest I get is puting them all the dictionaries in a list like below

```
lst = [{"bob": 20, "alex" :80},{"harry": 50, "bob" : 90},{"alex" : 40, "lee" : 20},{"lee" : 70, "harry" :40}]
```

after this I don't know what to do. I assume somehow loop through each of the key value pairs and put it in to a dictionary. Then if a key value is in the new dictionary you somehow add the value on to the existing key, but I cant seem to figure it out.Any help would be great

Comment: this is not valid python syntax `{"alex":80,40 , "bob":20,90 , "harry":50,40 , "lee":20,70}`

Answer (score 1):

You may use a  `collections.defaultdict`, then for each student, append its grade

```
result = defaultdict(list)
for subject in History, Maths, english, art:
    for student, grade in subject.items():
        result[student].append(grade)

print(result)  # {'bob': [20, 90], 'alex': [80, 40], 'harry': [50, 40], 'lee': [20, 70]}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BCsIwEEX3OcWnqxaCFK2oAfduPEHpItLUhtakpEEs0rPXTCwIzmqY92b@DJNvrdkty0WP3roJZ7yTm70lAtucI5G9eiUQx3xmV@nbMfJWOjcFY08GyRA4BUOZe6/HNjrrIgpyeqWo3wZHOh/5OjoQ/t6DKAJnjTayJ2VmjXWooQ3K9TuO@ATHmsQRzlWCIRTJHceT/HqjvXqMafZFVLpBB2M94RjxQ3GbRmVXheCyYv/TjRwGZer0mbHBaePTCLJl@QA)

```
History = {"bob": 20, "alex" :80}
Maths = {"harry": 50, "bob" : 90}
english = {"alex" : 40, "lee" : 20}
art = {"lee" : 70, "harry" :40}

final = {}
for d in [History, Maths, english, art]:
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k not in final:
            final[k] = []
        final[k].append(v)
print(final)
```

Output:

```
{'bob': [20, 90], 'alex': [80, 40], 'harry': [50, 40], 'lee': [20, 70]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final_dict={}

for el in lst:
    for person,value in el.items():
        if person not in final_dict:
            final_dict[person]=[value]
        else:
            final_dict[person].append(value)
```

*Output:*

```
{'bob': [20, 90], 'alex': [80, 40], 'harry': [50, 40], 'lee': [20, 70]}
```